# NS_ENUM - function definition is not allowed here

Tags: ios

I am receiving the error `function definition is not allowed here` on all three `enum`s. I recently updated to Xcode 6.0.1 and I am receiving that error now. How can I fix this error, should I avoid using this macro. I have also set the target SDK to ios 6.0 which supports these macros.

```
BConstants.h

#ifndef asdf_BPConstants_h
#define asdf_BPConstants_h


typedef NS_ENUM(NSUInteger, BTheme) {
    kField
};

typedef NS_ENUM(NSUInteger, BItem) {
    kBox
};

typedef NS_ENUM(NSUInteger, BMovementState) {
    kTouchUp,
    kTouchDown
};

#endif
```

Answer (score 28):

Importing `Foundation` should be enough.

```
@import Foundation;
```

Answer (score 16):

Importing UIKit fixed this for me.

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
```

Comment: To be clear, the order of lines matters here. You have to place the `NS_ENUM(...` block **after** you do your import. @alfavata (answer below) is correct, that `Foundation` is enough. If you need `UIKit` capabilities, importing `UIKit` brings `Foundation` along with it.